# How can I globally replace C-c with another key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

The key combination `C-c` is not convenient to type in the keyboard layout I use, and I'm trying to do change it globally. The goal is to replace every occurrence of `C-c` with another binding `<apps> d`, such that sending a message in Gnus would be `<apps> d <apps> d`, compiling in auxtex would be the same, and the user prefix key `C-c` would also always be `<apps> d`. The key `<apps>` is `<f19>` on my keyboard.

Reading the manual, it seems that I need to use `key-translation map`. It does work great with the translation of `<f19>` to `<apps>`

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<f19>") (kbd "<apps>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<apps> s") 'save-buffer)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work when I want to do this for `C-c`.

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<apps> d") (kbd "C-c"))
```

When I try to use it, I get

```
<apps> d is undefined
```

and if I look it up (`C-h k`), I see

```
<apps> d (translated from <f19> d) is undefined
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: A guess, a similar map (`input-decode-map`) has this in its documentation: "The events that come from bindings in \`input-decode-map' are not
themselves looked up in \`input-decode-map'." Which makes sense, if you think about it: this would be a way to prevent infinite translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your attempt is that `apps` comes from a translation via `key-translation-map`, and this output is not searched in `key-translation-map` recursively. If you omit `apps` altogether and work with `f19` directly, it works.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f19> s") 'save-buffer)
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<f19> d") (kbd "C-c"))
```

If you want to use the `apps` alias, you can make use of the fact that there are two similar translation maps: `input-decode-map` and `key-translation-map`. Use `input-decode-map` to declare virtual function keys corresponding to key sequences send by your keyboard, e.g. the translation from `f19` to `apps`. Use `key-translation-map` to make an internal translation in Emacs, e.g. from `apps d` to `C-c`.

```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<f19>") (kbd "<apps>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<apps> s") 'save-buffer)
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<apps> d") (kbd "C-c"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I tried using `local-function-key-map` and it also works. Is there a reason for using one over the other?

Comment: The difference with `local-function-key-map` is that `local-function-key-map` can be overridden with a global or local binding for `apps d`. Which come to think of it might be a feature rather than a bug.